# Add RSA login access to a new linux user

Tags: ssh, debian, rsa

I have automatically created rsa connection for user "root" via hosting installation script.

**I just added two new users and my question is how to configure them in SSH to login with their rsa keys?** Now when im trying to login with old root rsa-key but with new user name there appears *Server refused our key*.

I looked for this on stack but without help. For example I have a problem with finding ~/.ssh directory. My system is Debian 9.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: "For example I have a problem with finding ~/.ssh directory. My system is Debian 9." You might need to just create it. Anyway, this site is for professionals. Please hire one to help you out.

Answer (score 1):

This is called SSH passwordless access. If you google for it, you'll get tons of howtos. For example:

https://www.tecmint.com/ssh-passwordless-login-using-ssh-keygen-in-5-easy-steps/

Comment: But i dont want to disable passwords/key-passphrase. I need to login with putty generated passphrase and rsa file but as other user than root.

Comment: But this approach is supposed to be applied to all users, which shall have the passwordless login capability. It doesn't disable passwords.